# Concatenation of unequal dimension tensors in tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pytorch

Am new to tensorflow and would like to convert a pytorch code - into tensorflow code.. How to do i perform it?

```
X_train, Y_train = Variable(torch.Tensor(X[:-30])), Variable(torch.Tensor(Y[:-30]))
X_test, Y_test = Variable(torch.Tensor(X[-30:])), Variable(torch.Tensor(Y[-30:]))

X_train = X_train.view(X_train.size(0), -1)
Y_train = Y_train.view(Y_train.size(0), -1)

data = torch.cat([X_train, Y_train], dim=1)
print(type(data))
```